# OpenGL ES depth buffer android, can't get to work

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm unable to get the depth buffer working correctly on Android OpenGL ES 2.0. Regardless of what I do, the objects are always render in the order provided and completely ignore the depth buffer.

From what I've read, the default setup should have a depth buffer, but I've nonetheless tried every function I could think of to get it working:

```
//setup
setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
setEGLConfigChooser( true );

GLES20.glEnable( GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST );
GLES20.glDepthFunc( GLES20.GL_LEQUAL );
GLES20.glDepthMask( true );

//render
GLES20.glClearColor(0.8f, 0.5f, 0.8f, 1.0f);
GLES20.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

I  am placing objects at 0.5, 0.0, -0.5 in the z-axis. I can verify that this works since if I use a perspective view it will correctly alter the sizes of the objects (distant ones smaller) -- my vertex shader does nothing but apply the view matrix. If I'm correct I can't alter the depth in the fragment shader at all in ES, so that can't be wrong.

I'm stumped. I really have no idea what else I could check. Every search I do (in the web, or here) gives answers that don't seem to solve the problem (though it indicates people have had the problem for other reasons). Most examples in ES 2.0 don't actually have enough objects to test the depth buffer, so I can't be positive the sample code is correct either.

---

To comment: My "setup" section is called just after a call to "super" inside my derived GLSurfaceView, prior to setting the renderer. The "render" part is called first inside my renderes "onDrawFrame".

Comment: Are you calling GLES20 methods right after creating GLSurfaceView?

Comment: I clarified where I call these functions.

Comment: In that case you could try moving all GLES20 calls within rendering code.

Comment: I moved the three setup "gl" functions to onSurfaceCreated and it works. Thank you. Strange that no error/warning was printed in the logs.

Comment: You should answer you own question if you figured it out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

harism's comment was the correct answer. The below three functions can only be done once you have a rendering context. I put them in the onSurfaceCreated method and it works. You can also put them in the onDraw method if you change them during rendering.

```
GLES20.glEnable( GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST );
GLES20.glDepthFunc( GLES20.GL_LEQUAL );
GLES20.glDepthMask( true );
```

Comment: Using all three caused strange effects. Just adding .glEnable as you say solved my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Have you specified the buffer depth?  This might be the solution to your problem.

```
myGlSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
```

Comment: I don't think setting a 16-bit depth buffer makes any difference, because 16 bits is the default (see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setEGLConfigChooser(int, int, int, int, int, int). 24 bits should do it. See my answer below.

Comment: Huh, that was a long time ago. Not sure. But maybe it was meant more like "don't forget to configure it before you use it" and not especially having a 16 bit buffer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by using a 24-bit depth buffer instead of the default, which is 16 bits (so selecting a 16-bit depth buffer won't make any difference). I used

`myGlSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8,8,8,8,24,0);`

Incidentally I had the same problem, with effectively the same solution, on iOS (my code is a portable map renderer, so I need it to run on lots of platforms). The iOS fix was to call

`self.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24;`

in the init function of my GLKView-derived class.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using EglCore class from [Google/Android Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) samples  you need to uncomment line to enable depth buffer!

```
        int[] attribList = {
            EGL14.EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
            EGL14.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
            EGL14.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
            EGL14.EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
            //EGL14.EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16,
```

https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/gles/EglCore.java#L158

Comment: Surprised nobody else has found this answer helpful in 4 years :) Thanks for posting, this was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, neither `setEGLConfigChooser`, `glDepthFunc` nor `glDepthMask` is needed (they may be optional). To enabling depth buffer feature, just adding `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` in `onSurfaceCreated` should be sufficient. The cause of problem was in the other place.

The critical solution for me was to change this line **in `onDrawFrame`**:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

to

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

The outline is like below (in Kotlin):

```
override fun onSurfaceCreated(gl10: GL10, eglConfig: EGLConfig) {
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

    // Do something
}

override fun onDrawFrame(gl10: GL10) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT or GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    // Do something
}
```