# Objects visibility determined by order of rendering but not by their position with respect to view point

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, visibility

Im using OpenGL ES to draw a cube with each side in a different color.

Each side is made up of two triangles, 
I draw each side by first setting color using GLES20.glUniform4fv , and then drawing triangles using GLES20.glDrawElements .

The problem is that all the sides (triangles) are visible on the screen irrespective of if one side is behind the other.

The rendering is happening in the order I draw the sides, meaning the latest will overlap the old, but not based on the position of the side and vertices from the view point.

Please help if something has to be set prior so that objects visibility is determined by position of object and view point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various approaches to your problem like using depth buffer or tree-based algorithms. OpenGL ES has an in-built implementation of depth buffering. You can enable it by using `GLES20.glEnable( GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST )`. Don't forget to clear or invalidate (GLES 3.x) the depth buffer before drawing. Note however that there are difficulties when using it with partially transparent surfaces. The impact on performance depends on depth precision, depth buffer size and scene complexity.

Comment: Thanks Reaper, this solved it.           (The placement of depthtest enable and related function calls is from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866686/opengl-es-depth-buffer-android-cant-get-to-work)